# n Choose k using an integer type of n and k in java

Tags: java

I have been given a task that requires to use n and k to work out the n Choose k problem.
The condition I have is I can not use other data type other than `int`.
I'm not be able to use the package such as `BigInteger`.
The int `n` and `k` can be any number below 200.
How can I avoid the number grows too large? Because the program blows when `n > 20`.
Thanks.

**Wikipedia**: ["n Choose k" or "Binomial coefficient"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: You can't.  Ints can't hold numbers that large, and if that's all you can use, that's it.  If you could use arrays of ints, it would be doable but a PITA.  Collections of Integers would work nicer, but they aren't technically ints.  On second thought, you could simply output the representation of n choose k with the factorial formula.  But that's probably not what the instructor intends.

Comment: @Manuel Selva obviously it is

Comment: why not use a `long` for `n > 20`?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: Because of his assignment. He is not allowed to.

Comment: You could use an int array to represent an arbitrarily long number.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This is an assignment. Can you show me some codes that the int fits into an array and do math functions pls?

Answer (score 3):

use recursion relation: (n, k) = (n-1,k-1)+(n-1,k)

base cases: (n, 0) = 1; (0, k) = 0

Comment: @abh this will result in an overflow for large numbers

Comment: +1, that's the simpler way to keep the solution as low as possible. If the final solution is bigger than int.MaxValue, there are no solution.

Comment: @Scorpi0: yeah, the homework is probably just intended for learning recursion. One way is print out the addition literally: (200,100) = 1+0+0+1+0+... and just let it overflows the console :))

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem requires you to create your own data-structure that can hold huge numbers or alteast represent huge numbers. Once that is done the rest is trivial. You might want to look at the source code of BigInteger to see how they do it.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but he specified that he's not allowed to use anything but ints.  That's pretty specific and doesn't allow Object types.